# LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .ps

Tags: graphics, pdftex, ps

When I try to compile this file http://danjer.doudouke.org/_media/tech/dokutexit/playground.zip this error occurs:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .ps.
```

I'm using TeXworks Version 0.4.3 (MiKTeX 2.9) and pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes). Your question is answered [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=unkgrfextn).

Answer (score 22):

1. You could compile with pdfLaTeX, if you add the line

   ```
   \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
   ```

   for automatic conversion of the PS images to PDF. It requires the option --enable-write18 set. Check the TeXworks preferences, Typesetting, Processing tools, pdfLaTeX:

   [image: pdfLaTeX arguments]
2. You can compile it with XeLaTeX, which is directly supported by TeXworks. You can choose XeLaTeX in the drop-down menu.

   For compiling with XeLaTeX, remove these two lines from the preamble, as XeLaTeX natively supports UTF-8:

   ```
   \usepackage{ucs}
   \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
   ```
3. Use LaTeX in DVI-mode, and convert as needed, using dvips and ps2pdf, or dvipdfm(x). You can call `latex` at the command prompt, or define a new tool for TeXworks in the preferences:

   [image: TeXworks tools]

Comment: Seems to work! But there are now different errors. I will figure this out...

Comment: @powtac I was able to successfully compile that project both with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX, as described. If you encounter different problems or have follow-up questions, perhaps post a new question, with a link to this question.

Answer (score 3):

pdflatex can insert graphics in jpeg, pdf, and png formats. Can you convert your postscript image (assuming postscript since it has the .ps extension)?

Comment: What else beside pdflatex can I use?

Comment: you can use plain latex which can insert the postscript image, or stay with pdflatex but convert your image to png, pdf, or jpeg.

Comment: How can I receive plain latex in Windows? Is it part of GhostScript?

Answer (score 0):

When a user reported this error, I found that the .ps file was actually Encapsuled PostScript.  The error went away when the .ps file extension was renamed to .eps