# Reference undefined

Tags: cross-referencing, errors, lastpage

I receive the a `Reference "LastPage" undefined` error when trying to compile a document with this syntax:

```
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
```

What is necesarry to prevent this error? I'm using TeXworks Version 0.4.3 (MiKTeX 2.9) and pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Please supply a MWE, we do not know if you create the label, or if you use any packages, for instance `lastpage`?

Comment: What is a "MWE"?

Comment: Please see this: [Welcome](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and here is the proper link for [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231/7049).

Answer (score 11):

`\usepackage{lastpage}` is required, further you need to compile at least twice. The reason is, that the first compiler run writes the reference for that label to the `.aux` file, in the second compiler run it can be read in.

The package `lastpage` defines the label `LastPage`, and your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41742/latex-error-unknown-graphics-extension-ps) showed that this package is used. So just compile again.