# How do I install TeX/LaTeX on Windows

Tags: installing, windows

I am new to TeX/LaTeX. How do I install TeX on Windows (7)? It seems that there are many different implementations, so which one is best for my OS?

Comment: Joseph Wright wrote a great blog post about TeX on Windows, it's worth a read: [TeX on Windows: MiKTeX or TeX Live](http://www.texdev.net/2011/11/19/tex-on-windows-miktex-or-tex-live/)

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1706/how-do-i-get-started-with-latex-on-windows-xp

Comment: proTeXt walks you through the process: http://www.tug.org/protext/

Comment: Does this still apply for windows 10? I use Linux but wanted to do somethings on my windows 10 but it's not installed here and want to install now.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can choose between TeX Live and MiKTeX. In practice, it does not make a difference in which distribution you use. Especially if you are new to LaTeX. However, you should take care that you install the full version, with all packages, and not a minimal or base version.

You get MiKTeX from [**here**](http://www.miktex.org/2.9/setup) (choose the 'MiKTeX 2.9 Net Installer') and TeX Live [**here**](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

Both install a basic editor ([TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/)). I have the experience from my workshops with students, that they have problems with that editor. I introduced [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/) which worked quite well in the lectures.

Comment: Please add a short description of your student's problems with TeXworks.

Comment: Perhaps you could post such problems here as questions, one by one? So each problem could be answered hopefully with good explanation and perhaps even screenshots, which might help your students as well as further TeXworks users. Example of explaining using TeXworks with `write18` or in DVI mode: [LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .ps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41742/latex-error-unknown-graphics-extension-ps).

Comment: There is at least another TeX distribution, too: [W32TeX](http://w32tex.org/). It’s also interesting for MiKTeX users, because it provides some tools as Windows binaries missing in MiKTeX, especially `xindy` and the `lcdf-typetools`.

Answer (score 11):

Some hints beside the selection of distribution:
Don't install it in the `programs` folder.

You may get problems with the authorization concept of win7.

And important: No spaces in installation path! Some tools will get problems.

Comment: I assume that this applies to texlive mainly. Miktex never had such problems - at least I can not remember them. But texlive comes from  the unix world and uses perl, there spaces in paths are a real problem.

Comment: I am using texlive. But I think I got problems with other tools related to TeX (I remember to problems with (rail)[http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/rail])

Comment: What is the default installation folder of texlive. I hope its not in 'program files' folder.

Comment: I think it is c:/texlive. But I don't like it. Now I have c:/bin/texlive. But as I wrote, my first attempt with the windows default for applications make problems.