# LaTeX Download for Windows

Tags: installing, windows, distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install TeX/LaTeX on Windows 7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/how-do-i-install-tex-latex-on-windows-7)

I am looking for a full LaTeX download for use on Windows. I have looked on google, however there seems to be a lot of options, and I am not sure what to choose. Can anyone make any recommendations?

Comment: TeXlive and MikTeX are pretty much the standard anwers here. I agree with Christian about migration.

Comment: @RafaelChavez What do you mean?

Comment: This is not the right forum but I recommend Kile.

Comment: @CAF - I flagged the question for migration to TeX Stackexchange, so don't give up yet on getting some more recommendations and feedback about user experience with each. If you search that site for "latex download: Windows", you'll get a lot of "hits".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.  Your question is a duplicate of one already on the site: [What are the advantages of TeX Live over MikTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20036/2693).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: [BAKOMA](http://bakoma-tex.com/menu/about.php) can be a wise option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether this the best place to ask this question...
I recommend MikTeX for Windows, which is the most widely used LaTeX distribution for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can just download the latest MikTex from [here](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup). It installs in minutes and is the most common LaTeX framework for Windows. That is the best thing to download.

You have quite a number of choices for an editor though. I have been trying TexMaker recently which is quite good, but there are loads of others (WinEdt, Lyx, TexNicCenter etc.) Spoilt for choice.

Comment: One simple TeX editor is alredy included in shipped out MiKTeX and TeX Live: TeXworks. And LyX is a bit special, see [Wikipedia: LyX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LyX).

Comment: Is is just your personal impression that "MiKTeX is the most common LaTeX framework for Windows" or do you know any stats about that? At least amongst tex.sx users, this does not seem to be the case! See [TeX Community Polls](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1565)

Comment: Scratch that last part ... I didn't take into consideration that the poll also included non-Windows users.

Comment: Well OK, however even if it was the case, the guy is asking for a simple recommendation. MikTex is very popular and very easy to install and work with, and good for going on the 'safe side'. So although it is my personal opinion (I didn't look at any polls) its a good enough answer for new users who want a hassle free installation, which is what is being asked for.

Answer (score 1):

[ProTeXt](http://www.tug.org/protext/) comes bundled with few goodies (like TeXnicCenter and ghostscript) along with MiKTeX. It aims to be an easy-to-install TeX distribution for Windows, based on MiKTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I have used MikTeX for a long time and can support the recommendations given above. There are some minor differenes between MikTeX and TeXlive in which packages are included. But in the en you pretty much get almost eveything on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/). You can also look at the [linked MikTex-TeXlive question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-advantages-of-tex-live-over-miktex) for additional input.

Comment: No, you do **not** get almost all of CTAN, though due to “almost” it is to some degree debatable. Both MiKTeX and TeX Live lack parts. TeX Live is a bitmore predictable, because it restricts itself to packages and additional software with full open licenses. MiKTeX includes also stuff, that is just free as in “free beer”, but on the other hand it lacks things, and it is not clear, why they aren’t included.

Answer (score 0):

[Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/) is a good option, but this question should be migrated to TeX.SE.

Comment: LyX is *not* a TeX distribution.

Comment: Yes. But you have to remind that the OP first posted this on M.Se. When he posted that, it didn't have the *distributions* tag.