# I have installed TeXStudio and when I compile a file an error occurs

Tags: texstudio

I have installed TeXStudio and when I compile a file this error occurs.
What should I do?

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "naveed_thesis".tex
```

Comment: have you installed a tex system (texlive or miktex)  texstudio is just an editor

Comment: Maybe helpful: [How do I install TeX/LaTeX on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41808/124842).

Comment: That's not an error message.