# Kile won't recognize .ps images

Tags: graphics, postscript

I'm using Kile on Ubuntu 12.04, and I produce figures using gnuplot. Whenever I have a .ps figure in my .tex document:

```
\begin{figure}[H!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{image.ps}
\label{Figure}
\caption{caption}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I get an error message saying: `Unknown graphics type: ps`

I know I can convert it into .png, but the .png quality is not as good as .ps, besides, I used to use Live tex on Mac and didn't get this problem.

Any suggestion? I really care about the quality of the figure.

Comment: Are you processing with latex or with pdflatex?

Comment: As Gonzalo mentioned in his comment, the engine matters (`pdflatex` is not keen on `.ps` files, `latex` is). If you are using `pdflatex` you could try using the `auto-pst-pdf` package.

Comment: Duplicate? [LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .ps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41742)

Comment: unrelated to your question but `[H!]` doesn't look right `H` ignores all the float constraints anyway as it makes a non-floating box, so `!` is meaningless for an `H` float.