# Inserting PS and PSG graphics files

Tags: graphics, ps

I have some PS and PSG graphics files that I need to include in a document, graphics file types that I have no experience with. Similar questions have been asked on this site before, but, regrettably, I have not been able to use these tips to solve my problem. So please accept my apology for posting a similar question. My naive approach has been

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=4in]{image1.ps}
\includegraphics[width=125mm]{image2.psg}
\end{document}
```

This results in the error "unknown graphics extension". Using a suggestion from the post [LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .ps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41742/latex-error-unknown-graphics-extension-ps) I have then tried adding the line

```
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
```

This returns the error "shell escape' (or write 18) is not enabled". From the same post a suggestion for this problem is to set the " --enable-write18" option. It is not clear to me where/how I should set this option. I am using WinEdt 9 and would appreciate any help.

Comment: The `.ps` one will probably work if you rename it to `.eps` but I have no idea what a `.psg` file is so I can not suggest anything there, try to convert it to (say) pdf (google for anything that can do that)

Comment: After changing the file extension to EPS and adding `\usepackage{epstopdf}` the file now compiles. Hey, I have no idea what a PSG file is either, but I also changed the extension to EPS and this works also.  Thanks for your help...

Comment: To enable write18 on WinEdt please see the description under **Update** in the answer to [How can I enable write 18 on a MikTeX installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation)

Comment: Are you sure it's not a `PSD`file? This would be Adobe Photoshop format.

Comment: @Bernard, I can't me sure but I don't think so. Most likely misnamed PS files. They seemed to survive the change of file type to EPS though.

Comment: The main difference between .eps and .ps is a bounding box.

Comment: Did you look inside the ‘PSG’  file with your text editor? You'll probably see what it's supposed to be.

Comment: @Bernard, I just did so and it means little to me. Here is a sample: L3155 2013 L3156 2060 L3157

Comment: @alwaysask, I followed the steps in the post you sent, but I still get the `shell escape` error when i try to include PS files. When I change the file extension to ESP, no problems.

Sorry, my problem. When I compile with PDFLaTeX the error disappears, except I now need to find a style file luatex85.sty.

Comment: This does not look like  the code of a .ps or .eps type. Compare with the .ps file you have. Ps is a programming language.

Comment: @Bernard, a PS file does look different.

Comment: You need to add `--enable-write18` for all the engines (executables) you want to use, not just PDFLatex . Select them one by one and add the option to each of them (LuaLATex or whatever you want to use).

Comment: And you obtain a result with epstopdf?

Comment: If there's no secret, upload a PSG file somewhere so we can have a look at it (https://www.wetransfer.com/ for example).

Comment: @Bernard, changing PS and PSG file to extensions to ESP and using `\usepackage{epstopdf}` did the trick.

Comment: @Freakalien: Strange…

Comment: It is supposed to be a Page Segment File related to Advanced Function Presentation. However, based on [this description](http://www.file-extensions.org/psg-file-extension#description), that seems rather unlikely. @Bernard

Answer (score 3):

The .ps one will probably work if you rename it to .eps, and apparently in comments the .psg one is also PostScript and can be made to work as eps.

Strictly speaking EPS is a restricted, structured, form of PostScript, but often (or at least, sometimes) you do not need all the restrictions of EPS and just a standard PostScript file works if you *say* it is EPS.